# Extract JSON object from $resource.get promise

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, angular-resource, dhtmlx-scheduler

I have just started exploring AngularJS. Is there any way by which I can extract the original JSON returned from server?

I am trying to get some data using `$resource.get` from a WebAPI. The returned promise contains some additional properties compared to my original JSON.

When I assign this object (returned from `$resource.get`) to some of my Javascript controls (like DHTMLX Scheduler), it does not work correctly but if I use $http it returns pure JSON and the control works perfectly.

I am more interested in using $resource as it has been used in the rest of the Angular controllers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you have a service that's defined using a resource:

```
app.factory('LoginService', function($resource, API_URL) {
    return $resource(API_URL + '/login.json');
});
```

Then elsewhere in a controller (for example) you want to use that service:

```
var loginRequest = LoginService.get({
    email: email,
    password: password
}).$promise;

loginRequest.then(function onSuccess(response) {
    // access data from 'response'
    var foo = response.foo;
},
function onFail(response) {
    // handle failure
});
```

The key is that you need to access $resource.get().$promise, not $resource.get().

Comment: gr8, exactly same I was looking for. Thanks JVNick!!

Comment: np. glad you figured it out!